# How to find the rows containing the match string in datatable in my case?

Tags: c#, .net, select, datatable

I have a combo box which contains the years, Exampple: 2016,2017,2018  etc.

I have dt which has 5 columnc which contains date in 3 columns which are by name paydate,begindate, enddate. But the format of each date is dd/mm/yyyy .

What i have to do ?

I have to find all the rows which contains the selected year in combobox (cboYear). It could have been much simpler if there was just years in the rows of datatable but it has day and month with "/"
    so it is not able to match the string "2016" with "01-12-2016" and returns no rows by the folowing query :

```
//this cboYear.Text has lets say "2016 and paydate and other two column has date in format "dd/mm/yyyy""
 DataRow[] foundAuthors = dt2.Select("paydate= '" + cboYear.Text + "'" + " and " + "begindate= '" + cboYear.Text + "'" + " and " + "enddate= '" + cboYear.Text + "'");
 if (foundAuthors.Length != sdgvPayDates.Rows.Count-1)
 {
       MessageBox.Show("All rows must have same year as the selected year in combobox");
       return false;
 }
```

**How to get the rows which contains the selcted year by finding effective matching?**

If soemthing like  "like" operator in LINQ also exist ? so that it just find all the matching rows so that it could find the row even when "2016" the datatable contains 01/02/2016 format . Datatable contains this http://prntscr.com/ccx3zn

Comment: do you try this `DateTime.Now.Year` for getting your year from your date ?

Comment: The date is in datatable i cannot changethe format in datatable

Comment: can you please share your `DataTable` code ?

Comment: where you are getting date as this format `01-12-2016` ?

Comment: It is not database, it is dataset, it is in your app memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
string stringDate= "01-12-2016";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(stringDate);
int year = date.Year;
```

you can parse your date to `DateTime` and extract the year

**Edited:**
You can try approach mentioned in following code snippet, in which I have used LINQ to get the required data rows from data table.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("dateColumn");
 DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
 row[0] = "01-12-2016";
 dt.Rows.Add(row);

 int year = 2016;            
 DataRow[] foundAuthors = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("dateColumn")).Year == year).ToArray();
```

Comment: please re read the question. I have o find the rows in datatable which contains the date in formate "dd/mm/yyyy" by matching a string which has just year format "yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement, you want to select the whole year. So choose dates after first of January that year, and before 1st January next year.

```
int nextyear = Int32.Parse(cbo.Year) + 1;
DataRow[] foundAuthors = dt2.Select("paydate>='" + cboYear.Text + "-01-01' and paydate<"+ nextyear + "-01-01 ' and begindate>='" + cboYear.Text + "-01-01' and begindate<" + nextyear + "-01-01' and enddate>= '" + cboYear.Text + "-01-01' and enddate<" + nextyear + "-01-01';");
```